# How does 'if((x) || (y=z))' work?

Tags: c

I don't quite understand how the if statement in this case works. It evaluates the `x != 0` statement and when that is not true anymore, it assigns `z` to `y` and then `break`s the if statement?

```
int main()
{
    int x, y, z, i;
    x = 3;
    y = 2;
    z = 3;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if ((x) || (y = z)) {
            x--;
            z--;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d %d", x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: im not fluid in C but i believe it assigns `z` to `y` and then checks if `y` is true.

Comment: `y = z` is assignment not comparison!

Comment: If `x` is non-zero, it doesn't do the `y = z` part, and `if` body executes.  When `x` *is* zero, it does the `y = z` and if `z` was non-zero, the `if` body executes.  The `break` only happens when both `x` and `z` are zero.

Comment: Yes, I know. This code is from a book, and I'm trying to understand it.

Comment: Thank you Dimitri, It's all clear now.

Comment: If your book _really_ has `void main()` time to throw out that book.

Comment: @Chad why is it bad to have `void main()`  ?

Comment: @TonyTannous Because main **always** returns an `int`.

Comment: I think this example only exists to throw off the javascript kids.

Comment: `||`  is a conditional `or` it will execute the statement on the right only if the first condition is false.

Comment: @TonyTannous `main` is the one C function that does not *have to* explicitly return a value. Please read [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: @WeatherVane, Chad this is why I love being on StackOverflow. I learn everyday things I didn't know. Thanks guys!

Comment: @TonyTannous me too: Weather Vane, aged 105 3/4 .... if `main` returns at all, which in embedded it won't if there is nowhere to return *to*.

Comment: Is this what we call short-circuiting of C?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: To be fair, debuggers are not necessarily that great at showing the inner workings of single expressions.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Maybe you're right but that is not a reason to stop me or anybody from trying at least. :) For further confusions, we are anyways here.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I agree, it's always better to try to debug first, but in this particular case I'm afraid it won't be very helpful.

Comment: @NathanOliver C99 5.1.2.2.1 "It shall be defined with a return type of int ... or in some other implementation-defined manner." The book may be for some implementation that defines main to return void?

Comment: @NathanOliver In addition "In a freestanding environment (in which C program execution may take place without any benefit of an operating system), the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined." It is also possible the book regards programming for some embedded freestanding environment.

Answer (score 30):

Let's decompose that into smaller bits.

1. `if (x)` is the same as `if (x != 0)`. If `x != 0`, then you know the condition is `true`, so you don't do the other portion of the `if`.
2. If part 1. was `false`, then `y = z` assigns `z` into `y` and returns the final value of `y`.
3. From point 2., we can understand that `if (y = z)` is equivalent to `y = z; if (y != 0)`

---

Thus, from points 1. and 3., we can understand that :

```
if ((x) || (y = z)) {
    doSomething();
}
else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Is the same as :

```
if (x != 0) {
    doSomething();
}
else {
    y = z;
    if (y != 0) {
        doSomething();
    }
    else {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

It's true it's not particularly readable code though.

Answer (score 18):

No. `if ((x) || (y = z)) {`
in C-English is basically:

- if `x` is nonzero, evaluate the following code.
- if `x` is zero, set `y` to `z`.
- if `y` is nonzero, evaluate the following code.
- otherwise, break out of the loop.

If `x` is zero or `y` is zero, it breaks out of the loop.

Comment: `(y = z)` is only executed when `x == 0`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Correct. Clarified.

Comment: Your answer is even better than mine! ♥ the English translation. I'll remember that for future explanations.

Comment: There is a slight error here. The statement should read:
if `x` **IS** 0, set `y` to `z` and check if `y` isn't 0

Comment: @user1952500 Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Your last line should read "if `x` is zero **and** `y` is zero ... ".

Comment: I find “the following code” a bit misleading. Does it mean the following part of the expression? Or the body of the if-statement? (The latter is true, of course.)

Answer (score 7):

```
int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 3;
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (x != 0) {
            x = x-1;
            z = z-1;
        } 
        else {
            y = z;

            if (y != 0) {
                x = x-1;
                z = z-1;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d", x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: Ah now I see :). Ok, you should elaborate for OP.

Comment: Please do not preach for `void main()`.

Answer (score 3):

In C, there is [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so the statement `y=z` will not be evaluated until `x` becomes zero.

When `x == 0`, since `z` also decrements the same way, `z == 0`. Hence `y` will also be zero at that time due to the assignment. The statement `y=z` also returns `y` at this point which will be evaluated as a condition, and since that is also `0`, the `else break` will be hit.

Hence I believe the answer should be `0 0 0`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use assignment in an if statement, the result of the assignment is returned. so when you write :

```
if (x = y)
```

It will be always true unless the value of `y` is `0`, so `0` is returned as the result of assigning and the if statement is not executed.(anything except `0` is considered as true.)

So when you write :

```
if ( x || (x = y))
```

The if statement doesn't execute only if `x` is `0` & `y` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
if ((x) || (y = z))
```

there are two condition
one condition is 
`if ((x))` and another condition is `if ((y = z))` 
if one of them is true then if portion is execute otherwise else condition work

- only and only when both condition are false then else execute.